# my java program using scan read does not stop execution

Tags: java

I am a newbee in the Java world.  I wrote this program which reads in string array... When I run it, it never stops?!! what shall I add /change to make it end scanning?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Ex21 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i, n = 5;
    String c;
    ArrayList<String>words = new ArrayList<>();
    System.out.println("Enter multi strings: ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean loop = true;
    while(loop) {
        words.add(input.next());
        Collections.sort(words);
        System.out.println("The sorted list is: " + words);
    }
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you understand what `while(loop)` means?

Comment: while(loop) means as long as loop is true continue doing whats inside the while. you never false loop...

Comment: What are you trying to do ?

Comment: @SLaks WOuldn't no input makes the loop "False?  I guess not but then how would you fix it?

Comment: @Noob: I am trying to read in list of strings like ( sys, shi, eds, etc,) into an array, sort the array and print it.

Comment: @munir: No; you need to set the variable.

Answer (score 2):

A `while` loop by definition continues executing its body until its condition (in this case the variable `loop`) evaluates to `false`. You never set `loop` to `false` in the body of the `while`-loop, hence the condition will never evaluate to `false` and the loop will never end.

Additionally, it seems like you want to sort a list of words entered by the user. I wouldn't advise calling `Collections.sort` on every iteration of the loop. Maybe look into using a data structure that keeps its elements sorted on its own, such as a [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html). Or, at least, only call the `sort` method once, directly after the loop.

Answer (score 2):

```
while(condition) {
     /* do something */
}
```

means /* do something */ happens unless condition == false, in your case it alwats true, that is why it doesn't stop. So Java behaves ok in your case.

Answer (score 0):

`while(loop)` with `loop` always having the value `true` in your program is a so called `endless loop`, as the name says it never ends and this is what you are experiencing.

To make a loop stop you have to set the value of `loop` to `false` if some condition is fulfilled or terminate the loop using the key word `break`.

A condition may be for example having a certain word witch lets your loop terminate when it is entered, something like `"exit"`

Here is an example how you could set `loop` to `false`

```
String word = input.next();
boolean loop = ! "exit".equalsIgnoreCase(word);
while (loop) {
    words.add(word);
    Collections.sort(words);
    System.out.println("The sorted list is: " + words);
    word = input.next();
    loop = ! "exit".equalsIgnoreCase(word);
}
System.out.println("Bye!");
```

Here is an other example how you could cancel the loop using `break`

```
while (true) {
    String word = input.next();
    if("exit".equalsIgnoreCase(word)) {
        break;
    }
    words.add(word);
    Collections.sort(words);
    System.out.println("The sorted list is: " + words);
}
System.out.println("Bye!");
```

Note that the word `exit` is banned from the set that your arraylist can contain, You can change the program though to have it saved  too.

Comment: You're welcome! If this answer could help you then you might want to accept it ;-)